# How can a virtual directory path appear case sensitive?

Tags: asp.net

Hopefully I can explain completely providing real info

To start with then we have a LinkButton whose text is actually an image tag.

The image it links to is a Png and resides in a folder in the web directory.  This is IIS V6 and win Server 2003.

The path is http://webaddress/Admin/Images/image.png

Admin is a virtual directory configured in IIS.

The above url doesn't work but if you change it to http://webaddress/admin/Images/image.png (lowers case 'a') then the image is served, change it back to 'A' and it takes you to login, you log in and it loops back to log in.  change to 'a' and voila the image is served. Weirdly this problem doesn't always occur and I have hunted for a resolution for days to no avail. Any ideas?

Thanks

As requested this is the complete link button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCommitAll" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"><asp:Image ID="imgCommitAll" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Grid/confirm_16.png" AlternateText="Commit All Changes" />&nbsp;Commit All</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't it be easier to use an `ImageButton`?

Comment: Sure that would be easier. Although it would not correct the problem i'm having which is the image is not always served and I do not know why... yet :)

Comment: Hi did you find an answer for this? I know the answer below is marked as the answer but from your comments afterwwards it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: No unfortunately this was never resolved and the problem still exists. Something I will revisit one day.

Comment: Bummer. We're having the same issue on IIS 6 and WS 2003 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post the whole LinkButton tag?

If Admin is a virtual directory then your image url should be like ~/Images/image.png

If so, do you have your virtual directory placed under the root with also a map called admin? In this case, try to rename it to "Admin", but don't forget to change the path in IIS for your virtual Directory.

I've had a similar problem before.

Hope this helps,

Arne

Comment: The virtual directory 'Admin' is placed under the root of the website and Admin is itself a tiny little site.

Comment: So in the real directory structure, like /wwwroot/website/. The map beneath is called 'Admin' or 'admin'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly however the Application name is 'Admin' and the name in IIS is also Admin. The folder it actually maps to is called BackEnd

Comment: Mass update it's not case sensitivity as the sole cause :(. I don't think i'm no the right lines yet.

Comment: I don't fully get this "change it back to 'A' and it takes you to login, you log in and it loops back to log in." If you login, you should be able to see the page with the button on it (with or without image)? If the page doesn't show the image, look at the source code where the image is supposed to be and look what url it renderred, might help you on the way.


Also, does everything work correctly on your local machine?